# Does tag order matter?

Tags: support, tags

I've seen edits from trusted users who didn't alter the individual question tags, but switched their order. Is this done by a site rule, or for SEO? Is the idea to put priority tags first? Has this been covered somewhere?

Comment: Do you have an example? I highly doubt folks are editing questions solely to change the tag order, and I question if that's even possible. (I just tried it on this question, to no effect)

Comment: I likely won't find the one I'm thinking of, but I'll attach an example the next time I find one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's automatic. The site orders tags by their popularity (number of questions tagged with a tag), regardless of what order you enter them in. If the popularity of the tags changed after the last edit, even if the editor does not touch the tags the tags will still be show as reordered on the revision diff.

See: [Diff shows tag being added and removed in the same revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56216/diff-shows-tag-being-added-and-removed-in-the-same-revision)

Comment: That last sentence is the key. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to see one such edit because I'm pretty sure that's not actually possible.

Tags are automatically ordered from left to right by role (required/mod or normal), then popularity (AFAIK that's just how many questions use it).